# Durandal mapRoute, with ID target container

Tags: durandal

I searched how I can use durandal and maproute for specified, the id of result of maproute result.
For example how to have two applicationHost container, and how to specified in the maproute method the target of id container?

I search to make this:

```
div id="applicationPrincipal"

div id="applicationSecond"

 router.mapNav('welcome', 'applicationPrincipal');

 router.mapNav('profile', 'applicationSecond');
```

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router pluggin uses sammyjs and sammyjs can only be used per browser window instance because it listens to the windows location (url bar).

When the window location changes then sammyjs knows to run a method assigned to that route.

So, I dont think you will be able to use the routerjs pluggin for 2 applicationHost containers.  Maybe you can.. I've just never seen it done.